# Web audio not playing through iframe in Chrome version 59

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, html5-audio

In my application I am using one static HTML page. I have loaded an external domain URL (a games URL) in an iframe. After loading the page, sound was not playing in Chrome browser (version 59) but video was playing. All other browsers can play the sound, as well as lower versions of Chrome.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="iframe" src="http://xyz...." ></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sentences improvements, grammar/syntax corrections, code reformatting

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus What's wrong with how the code is formatted?

Comment: @freginold when I found this post, the code wasn't formatted at all. I added some indenting. I also corrected some syntax/grammar aspects. You proposed some other edits later, and they need to be approved before other users can see them. If you click on the `edited tot mins ago` link, you can see the history of edits of this post (and how was the code originally written).

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus Oh okay, gotcha, I didn't see that you had reformatted it. Thought maybe I was missing something.